# Can partitioning help speed up inserts on a very large table?

Tags: sql-server-2012, performance, partitioning, enterprise-edition

Some background:

- SQL 2012 Enterprise
- OLTP table currently at 1B records
- records increase 5-10M per day
- SAN lun with flash storage
- two indexes (one clustered identity int)

What we have noticed is a gradual slowing of INSERTs over time, which will eventually become an issue to the business if left unchanged.

The question:
We are planning to transition to use partitioning on this table soon, primarily for space management, but the main question here is whether partitioning can help improve the performance of INSERTs. (We know about performance increases for SELECTs already, please do not comment on that side of things if possible.)

I have done a fair amount of searching forums, etc, but have not found anything specific to INSERTs and partitioning. It seems reasonable to me that this would help maintain speed over time, given that we will partition on "date inserted" and that the INSERTs would always be directed to the most recent partition, but looking for confirmation.

Thanks all.

UPDATE:
To clarify: a staging table (for switching in) is not an option due to the OLTP nature and needing to read the data out immediately after inserting, both of which cannot be delayed awaiting a switch in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: yes it can help, because it's theoretically instantaneous. You would insert your data into a staging table with the same definition as your main partitioned table, and then switch it into the partitioned table, which is a metadata operation (schema lock).

Long answer: it might make performance suffer over the long run to have such a large table, and unless you move to later versions of SQL Server, statistics updates are quite difficult to manage.

If this is a read-heavy table, I'd consider using *view partitioning* instead. Each month (for example) would get its own table, with check constraints on a date column to help the query optimizer know where the data is physically stored, and a view over the top of that:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM period201501
UNION ALL
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM period201502
...
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM period201608
```

(or whatever). Then your metadata operation is the update of the view, as opposed to the switching in of the partitioned table.

Comment: Thanks @Randolph for the comments so far. The SELECT performance is good and I don't have any future concerns there. To clarify: The INSERTs cannot be sent to a staging table (for future switching in, which I understand) due to the OLTP nature of the table and needing to read data out immediately after insert; so unless I'm missing something, staging is not an option.

Comment: Do those other 1B rows matter at all for today's inserts/queries? Or is that historical information? If it's historical then you use staging as the active table and pop it over to the historical on some interval. If those 1B rows are needed for today's queries then you have a problem that is probably best solved with Partitioned Views (albeit with more maintence development overhead) until you can use SQL 2014 or later and take advantage of Incremental Statistics

Comment: I'd strongly suggest going with partitioned views then. All the same, I'm not sure how waiting for the switch-in is going to cause any downtime. It's really very fast. Have you tested it?

Comment: @Duffy unfortunately the 1B are not historical. The structure of Partitioned Views is something we've been discussing also, we are just trying to hone in on the technicalities of INSERT performance possibly improving with partitions. I'll give the post a little more time to see if other information surfaces. Appreciate your insights.

Comment: @RandolphWest Yes we may be headed, at least structurally, toward Partitioned Views, with the hope also that INSERT performance will stabilize at worst and improve at best. We use switch-ins on other tables and you are correct about the speed of it, but it's also when we can build up those inserts over time and then switch them in as a batch, which is not an option here. I'll give the post a little more time to see if any new ideas arise. Thanks for your input.

Comment: You may be able to go with a hybrid solution then ... partitioned view over historic partitioned table and new staging, and when the new gets big enough, switch that in during a low activity period.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on a lot of circumstances. For the most part Partitioning is primarily a benefit via concurrency for INSERTS/UPDATES/DELETES and query optimizer shortcuts when every related query uses the partitioning filter. Usually a smaller partition will perform better for the former as you surmised.

However, the partitioning overhead can just as likely cause performance problems depending on the complexity involved. You should try looking over your indexing and table design before trying partitioning, but if you're sure about moving to partitioning (or need to for disk reasons) the best possible INSERT performance you can get out of Partitioning relies on Partition Switching.

The high level premise is you insert the data into a staging heap table throughout the day and then when you're ready to move it into the partition apply the matching indexes and constraints. You can then use the Switch commands to pop the new 'partition' into your larger partition table as a new partition. Details can be found [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191160(v=sql.105).aspx) and a more detailed overview [here](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/03/how-decide-if-should-use-table-partitioning/).

This is primarily used for data warehousing so depending on your primary key structure and/or business needs this INSERT method may not work for you. You can also make that staging table an active component versus a heap you're dumping into with the added performance implications of doing such.

Comment: Thanks @Duffy - please see comment to Randolph as it pertains to your answer as well.